# How can I print the content of a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

`labels` is a dictionary of dictionaries :

```
{"1":{"id":"1","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4802","xMin":"4770","yMax":"156","yMin":"141"},"2":{"id":"2","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4895","xMin":"4810","yMax":"157","yMin":"141"},"3":{"id":"3","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4923","xMin":"4903","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"},"4":{"id":"4","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4956","xMin":"4931","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"}}
```

what I want is :

```
for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
    drawLabels(
      labels[i].id,
      labels[i].xMin,
      labels[i].xMax,
      labels[i].yMin,
      labels[i].yMax
    );
  }
```

I have 4 dictionaries in the main dictionary so I want their content used 1 by 1 but labels.length isn't working not even the way I'm accessing my dictionary elements below.

How can I fix my code to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`labels` isn't an array.

You should do it like this :

```
for (let i in labels){
    if(labels.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        drawLabels(
            labels[i].id,
            labels[i].xMin,
            labels[i].xMax,
            labels[i].yMin,
            labels[i].yMax
        );
     }
}
```

Comment: i see how can i know how many elements as in keys a javascript dictionary has instead of  labels.length

Comment: `Object.keys(labels).length`

Comment: it's working [fine](https://jsfiddle.net/71t6xb14/) for me. Do you mind sharing the rest of your code?